# How to #set a variable to make it available in an included velocity template

Tags: liferay, velocity

I'm creating a custom theme for Liferay, I wish to include the footer within each page layout individually. Unfortunately, I don't appear to have access to the $full_templates_path variable within the page layout files. I have had no luck manually storing the value with #set and then accessing that value within the included template.

In a vanilla theme, processing of files is something like this:

```
portal_normal.vm:
  1) some init, doctype, etc.
  2) #parse("$full_templates_path/header.vm")
  3) $theme.include($content_include)
    a) custom_layout_1.tpl
    b) chat portlet
  4) #parse("$full_templates_path/footer.vm")
```

For layout purposes, I need to deviate from this pattern, like so:

```
portal_normal.vm
  1) some init, doctype, etc.
  2) #parse("$full_templates_path/header.vm")
  3) $theme.include($content_include)
    a) custom_layout_1.tpl
      i) #parse("$full_templates_path/footer.vm")
    b) chat portlet
```

When I try this, tomcat errors out because $full_templates_path is not defined within custom_layout_1.tpl. I tried to fix this problem by doing the following within portal_normal.vm

```
#set($full_footer_path = "$full_templates_path/footer.vm")
$theme.include($content_include)
```

And then, within custom_layout_1.tpl, I do this where I'd like the footer markup emitted:

```
#parse("$full_footer_path")
```

However, tomcat still errors out, saying that $full_footer_path is not defined.

When I hard-code the value of $full_templates_path into #parse statement in custom_layout_1.tpl, everything works fine, but that seems like a hack to me.

Ideally, this should do the right thing for the right reasons, not just because I used a lot of duct tape.

Any suggestions for ways to implement the inclusion of a template file from within a custom page layout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue could be due to your velocity configuration.

The following property should be false `velocimacro.permissions.allow.inline.local.scope` if you want to access variables set in one template to be accessible in another

Comment: Is there any other way to accomplish this? I'm not sure I want to make a global change to the environment to solve this single problem. I'd like to limit the chance for unintended consequences.

Comment: This [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5014956/669645) to a similar question looks like it does what you're after

Answer (score 0):

You may have miss-typed your question but shouldn't `#set($full_footer_path = "$full_templates_path/footer.vm"` have a close bracket at the end...

```
#set( $full_footer_path = "$full_templates_path/footer.vm" )
```

It might also help to wrap `$full_templates_path` in curly braces to distinguish it from the rest of the text i.e `${full_templates_path}`

Comment: Also: the curly braces are not the problem. That same code works perfectly in portal_normal.vm